# How can Write Multiple and conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

Respected Developers , 
                      I have following Mysql query which give me wrong result , query is something like that

```
`select * from users
 where (Name='hashaam' or LastName='zahid' or Gender='male') and
 (City='New York' and State='NY') and
 Type=2 and 
 UserId NOT IN (select UserId from profile_detail where 
 UserId=user_profile.UserId)`
```

There are two 'AND' important conditions. Those are

`Type=2 and UserId Not IN... Rest are received from input.

WhenEver I Execute this query it's not only giving me wrong result but also gives me duplicate record(Even though there is no Duplicate record in table)

How Can I Write Multiple "And" Query ? Many Thanks For Helping .

Comment: If there are no duplicate records in the table, you cannot get duplicate records in your result with this query. So either there are duplicates in the table or the programm you are selecting the records with is buggy or you are simply mistaken about the duplicate results.

Comment: And what do you consider wrong results? Show sample data and result. If your column names are proper, there should be no duplicate IDs (ID means identification; with a table's `id` you identify one record). So with `Id=1` the query should return either one or no record.

Comment: `select * from users where (Name='hashaam' or lastname='hashaam' or Gender='male') and (City='New York' or State='NY') and BusinessType=2 and UserId NOT IN (select UserId from profile_detail where UserId=user_profile.UserId)`

Comment: You are using OR's - which can produce many results

Comment: Grantly Please Tell Me How Can Write This Query

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner, you have no joins so I can't see a reason for duplicate rows. Can you share your data and incorrect ouput?

Anyway You can try to remove the last condition and see whether there are duplicates

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner too. There's no way this query can give duplicates unless the data in the table contains duplicates. Another possible explanation is that the query you posted in this question is not the query that you are having trouble with. If that's the case, we can't guess what the actual troublesome query looks like, so there's no way anyone here can help.

Answer (score 0):

The request should not return duplicate rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
   users
WHERE  
  (Name='hashaam' OR LastName='zahid' OR Gender='male') 
AND
 City='New York' 
AND 
  State='NY' 
AND
 Type=2 
AND 
 UserId NOT IN (
                SELECT 
                   UserId 
                FROM 
                   profile_detail 
                WHERE 
                   UserId=user_profile.UserId
                 )
```

Comment: Wish I have  Point to Make You Answer Correct Thanks For Replying.